# Dealing with time intervals in Python?

Tags: python

I need to parse string representation, such as '1 year', '2 days' etc. into ISO8601 formatted period. The end result needs to be same as [DateInterval::createFromDateString](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.createfromdatestring.php) in PHP

As a placeholder, I've hard-coded small set of values that I know will appear in vast majority of cases, but obviously, this is not satisfying solution long term:

```
class Interval(object):
    _map = {
        '1 MONTH': 'P1M',
        '6 MONTH': 'P6M',
        '1 YEAR': 'P1Y',
        '7 DAY': 'P7D',
        '5 DAY': 'P5D',
        '1 DAY': 'P1D',
        '2 WEEK': 'P2W',
        '1 WEEK': 'P1W',
        '2 DAY': 'P2D',
        '2 YEAR': 'P2Y',
        '12 MONTH': 'P12M',
    }

    @staticmethod
    def convert(period):
        if period not in Interval._map.keys():
            #  log error
            return ''

        return Interval._map[period]
```

Is there a clean way to do this, rather then hard-code?

Comment: [`pandas.to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html)

Comment: May be [daterange parser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/DateRangeParser) will help you?

Comment: @A.N. I'm looking at the documentation, it seems to solve completely different problem? Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, my answer isn't correct for your case, pandas.to_timedelta is a really, what you need.